# Whether the norm of linear operator equal to the absolute of determinant of matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $f:\Omega\rightarrow R^n$ is a linear operator, $\Omega$ is a bounded open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.$A=\{a_{ij}\}$ is the matrix of the linear operator.

whether $||f||=|det(A)|$ ?

Comment: No, because there are matrices with $\det=0$ and this implies that $||f||=0$ for such linear operators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not be true for any norm (if $n\geq2$, at the very least).

Note in particular that $\|2f\|=2\|f\|$, while $\det(2f)=2^n\det(f)$. Note also that there exist non-zero $f$ with determinant $0$.

Comment: Do you know how to understand if $detf\ne 0$, $f$ has bounded inverse ?

Comment: The determinant is highly dependent on the number of dimensions in the space and doesn't have a general analog in infinite dimensional spaces. The situation is similar to that of trace. Consider, for example, the determinant of $2I$.

Comment: If $A$ is a trace-class operator, however, it makes some sense to talk about the determinant of $I+A$ or $\exp(A)$.

Comment: Note also that the spectral radius of an operator behave almost, but not exactly like a norm in finite dimensional spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly it's not true, take a non invertible operator (different from the trivial one), then $det(A) = 0$ but $f\neq 0$